# Crontab Not Working Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, cron

I am using crontab in ubuntu to send a csv to an email everyday, however it's not sending out. Why?

btw, i'm using laravel 4.2

**UPDATED CRONTAB**
crontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/.../app/controllers/CronTask.php > /var/www/html/.../public/cronoutput.txt
```

The functions of generating csv and send the csv to email are in CronTask.php. I wanna see the log of the cron so the log is cronoutput.txt.

What's the problem?

Comment: Does that same command work if you type it directly at a command prompt?

Comment: @lurker i tested on cmd, it returns 'command not found'

Comment: If it can't find the command, then the `crontab` isn't going to work. Does `/etc/php5/apache2` exist? And why are you using `apache2` to execute a `php` script? Why aren't you running the `php` command?

Comment: are you running the php script through the php interpreter?

Comment: @lurker i thought the etc part should be Configuration File (php.ini) Path which can be found on phpinfo()

Comment: @Orangepill what is php interpreter?

Comment: No, you need to run the `php` interpreter on your `php` file to execute it. `crontab` wants a command.

Comment: also known as the cli.... it the actual php executable.. probably should appear in crontab like  `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/.../app/controllers/CronTask.php > /var/www/html/.../public/cronoutput.txt`

Comment: @lurker i guess it's usually on /usr/bin/php right? :)

Comment: @Orangepill thanks, just changed. waiting result. :)

Comment: @Orangepill still no sending out. :(

Comment: Run the command directly from the command line and see what you get.

Comment: @Orangepill still not found. :\

Comment: you need to figure out what the path to your command is first.... the triple . in the path looks suspect.

Comment: @Orangepill you mean the CronTask.php path?

Comment: yes... first place I would look is `/var/www/app/controllers/CronTask.php`

Comment: @Orangepill wow i tested on cmd and it doesnt return 'command not found' anymore! but still not writing log and not sending email. :\ i'm confirm the CronTask.php is in the correct path

Comment: @Orangepill my log has changed! it will generate new line every minute but the content is all blank. that means the crontab is running isnt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because i'm using laravel, so need to use laravel artisan command to run the crontab in ubuntu. i referred to this site to create command: https://sonnguyen.ws/laravel-4-and-crontab/

then put all the csv generation and email to fire function. it's done.

app/commands/FirstCommand.php

1. php artisan command:make FirstCommand
2. change protected $name = 'user:active';
3. add generate csv and email in fire function. eg: echo "User activated"
4. remove arguments in array in getArguments function

app/start/artisan.php

1. Artisan::add(new FirstCommand);

in terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

command in crontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/project/artisan user:active >> /var/www/html/project/public/cronoutput.txt
```